# Jquery not loading properly in ie

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have a WIP portfolio site here:

http://benliger.webatu.com/

I have a few events running jquery in order to change page which seems to work fine in firefox and chrome. The strange thing is when I try it in IE 11, the change page function does not work. Upon inspecting element I got a message saying

"SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'easeInBack' 
jquery.min.js, line 2 character 87746"

When I trace the error in the jquery file it says that the file route folder is ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3 which doesn't sound right as I have not referenced this URL anywhere in my code and I imagine my change page function (found in changepage.js) is not working as its running of this older version of jquery.

If someone could please explain to me whats going on here that would be great, also how to fix it :)

Comment: IE11 is a strange beast, and jQuery 1.8.3 may not be properly equipped to deal with it. Any chance you can use a more recent release?

Comment: thats the thing that confuses me, im pretty sure im using jquery 1.11.1 so no idea why its loading in an older one. Ive tried clearing cache as well but no glory

Comment: That's strange indeed. Your page source does include release 1.11.1 and nothing else. Could release 1.8.3 be somehow loaded through your analytics script?

Comment: well, im not using analytics but since i am using a free host for testing they might be doing so. I wonder if i would have the same problem on a proper host. Anyway really stuck on what could be causing this :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking in your link, you can see that the host company is adding their own Analytics, which includes the jQuery v1.8.3 library automatically:

```
<script src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://stats.hosting24.com/popup/popup.js"></script>
<style type="text/css" media="screen"></style>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
<div class="bModal __bPopup1" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; z-index: 9998; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0.7; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></div>
<div class="popup" id="visas_style_div" style="left: 350px; top: 49.5px; position: absolute; z-index: 9999;"></div>
</body>
</html>
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
```

You can run this bit of script in your page to remove this library:

```
$(function () {
    $('script[src*="1.8.3"]').remove();
});
```

Try adding it to your page `head`, and if it doesn't work, place it immediately before you close the `body`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mr5aytob/)

If you can't manage to remove the old library, you can always work out conflicts:

```
// Managing the jQuery conflicts.
jQuery.noConflict();
(function ($) {
    // A single document ready event handler.
    $(function () {

        // All your script goes here...

    });
})(jQuery);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/rqbbnx9f/1/)

[jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

This will make sure that your scripts will be looking for the library you've chosen to work with, and not that old one.

Comment: hmm I tried your first suggestion and it still wouldnt work. With the second option i added $.noConflict( true ) script at the end of the body container to try force it out but sitll no joy. Am i doing this right?

Comment: Did you get any errors in your browser console when trying the first option?

Comment: the only error i got was the one that I had originally with the jQuery function: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'easeInBack' 
jquery.min.js, line 2 character 87746

Comment: you can check the link again as ive implememnted your suggested change at  the end of the body

Comment: I've noticed you have multiple document ready event handlers across your scripts. Ideally, you should have just one. Put this line: `$('script[src*="1.8.3"]').remove();` as the first one when your document is loaded (considering that you _fixed_ your scripts and have a single document ready now).

Comment: If you want to try the `.noConflict()` method, and also stick up all your scripts into a single document ready event handler, you can refer to this jsFiddle I've created: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/rqbbnx9f/1/

Comment: Check your HTML markup, because you have `<a>` tags within a `<ul>`, and this is invalid.

Comment: your fiddle JS works perfectly after a quick copy and paste :) thank you so much. I guess i'm a bit confused as to where exactly i should use document ready event handler. I see in your fiddle you havn't used it at all so is it best to just leave it out altogether?

Comment: Actually it's being used, but as recommended, just once. I used a shortcut: `$(function() {});`.

Comment: To work out the conflict between the two versions, I just wrapped your code within `(function($) {})(jQuery);` which keeps the scope of `$` to be used.

Comment: If you need the `li` to be linked somewhere, add the `a` tags within them: `<ul><li><a ...>...</a></li></ul>`. That's the correct markup.

Comment: Ah ok, makes sense I didnt know $(function() {}); was a shortcut for doc ready...

Comment: perfect will make those amends. Thank you!!