# Javascript and Jquery Conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im having a problem, when i delete this code below, the video player popup player works but my contact form doesnt.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I have added the Script for no conflict but its still now working, here are my JS and Jquery codes which are in the head tag. Any help would be appreciate it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var j = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>

<!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.3"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.2" media="screen" />

<script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/WDP87vS0EeKnIhIxOUCPzg.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        /*
         *  Simple image gallery. Uses default settings
         */

        $('.fancybox').fancybox();

        /*
         *  Different effects
         */

        // Change title type, overlay closing speed
        $(".fancybox-effects-a").fancybox({
            helpers: {
                title : {
                    type : 'outside'
                },
                overlay : {
                    speedOut : 0
                }
            }
        });

        // Disable opening and closing animations, change title type
        $(".fancybox-effects-b").fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'over'
                }
            }
        });

        // Set custom style, close if clicked, change title type and overlay color
        $(".fancybox-effects-c").fancybox({
            wrapCSS    : 'fancybox-custom',
            closeClick : true,

            openEffect : 'none',

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'inside'
                },
                overlay : {
                    css : {
                        'background' : 'rgba(238,238,238,0.85)'
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // Remove padding, set opening and closing animations, close if clicked and disable overlay
        $(".fancybox-effects-d").fancybox({
            padding: 0,

            openEffect : 'elastic',
            openSpeed  : 150,

            closeEffect : 'elastic',
            closeSpeed  : 150,

            closeClick : true,

            helpers : {
                overlay : null
            }
        });

        /*
         *  Button helper. Disable animations, hide close button, change title type and content
         */

        $('.fancybox-buttons').fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',

            prevEffect : 'none',
            nextEffect : 'none',

            closeBtn  : false,

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'inside'
                },
                buttons : {}
            },

            afterLoad : function() {
                this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
            }
        });


        /*
         *  Thumbnail helper. Disable animations, hide close button, arrows and slide to next gallery item if clicked
         */

        $('.fancybox-thumbs').fancybox({
            prevEffect : 'none',
            nextEffect : 'none',

            closeBtn  : false,
            arrows    : false,
            nextClick : true,

            helpers : {
                thumbs : {
                    width  : 50,
                    height : 50
                }
            }
        });

        /*
         *  Media helper. Group items, disable animations, hide arrows, enable media and button helpers.
        */
        $('.fancybox-media')
            .attr('rel', 'media-gallery')
            .fancybox({
                openEffect : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none',
                prevEffect : 'none',
                nextEffect : 'none',

                arrows : false,
                helpers : {
                    media : {},
                    buttons : {}
                }
            });

        /*
         *  Open manually
         */

        $("#fancybox-manual-a").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open('1_b.jpg');
        });

        $("#fancybox-manual-b").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open({
                href : 'conscious-video.html',
                type : 'iframe',
                padding : 5
            });
        });

        $("#fancybox-manual-c").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open([
                {
                    href : '1_b.jpg',
                    title : 'My title'
                }, {
                    href : '2_b.jpg',
                    title : '2nd title'
                }, {
                    href : '3_b.jpg'
                }
            ], {
                helpers : {
                    thumbs : {
                        width: 75,
                        height: 50
                    }
                }
            });
        });


    });
</script>

<!------Autoresponder---->
<script type="text/javascript">  
    /* <![CDATA[ */    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var close_note = $("#note");
        close_note.click(function () {
            j("#note").slideUp(1000, function () {
                j(this).hide();
            });
        });

        $("#ajax-contact-form").submit(function() {
            $('#load').append('<center><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Currently Loading" id="loading" /></center>');

            var fem = $(this).serialize(),
                note = $('#note');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "contact.php",
                data: fem,
                success: function(msg) {
                    if ( note.height() ) {          
                        note.slideUp(1000, function() {
                            $(this).hide();
                        });
                    } 
                    else note.hide();

                    $('#loading').fadeOut(300, function() {
                        $(this).remove();
                        if(msg === 'OK') {
                            $('input').val("");
                            $('textarea').val("");
                        }   
                        // Message Sent? Show the 'Thank You' message and hide the form
                        result = (msg === 'OK') ? '<div class="success">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>' : msg;

                        var i = setInterval(function() {
                            if ( !note.is(':visible') ) {
                                note.html(result).slideDown(1000);
                                clearInterval(i);
                            }
                        }, 40);    
                    }); // end loading image fadeOut
                 }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
    /* ]]> */
</script>
```

Comment: Including two different (very different, in this case) versions of jQuery is always a recipe for disaster. If the contact form code really relies on such an ancient version of the library, it probably should not be used anyway.

Comment: Why are you including two versions of jQuery? Use one or the other.

Comment: I just answered a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522507/jquery-not-loading-properly-in-ie/

Comment: And another one. So, two just today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524704/conflict-between-datepicker-and-jstree-or-multipul/

Answer (score 1):

Do not use two versions of jQuery inside of the same page (not recommended).

```
jQuery.noConflict()
```

Is supposed to be used when you are using two different libraries fighting for the $ (which is an alias for jQuery).

> Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just
>   as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so
>   all functionality is available without using $. If you need to use
>   another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, return control of $ back
>   to the other library with a call to $.noConflict(). Old references of
>   $ are saved during jQuery initialization; noConflict() simply restores
>   them.

But... in your case... docs says:

> If for some reason two versions of jQuery are loaded (which is not
>   recommended), calling $.noConflict( true ) from the second version
>   will return the globally scoped jQuery variables to those of the first
>   version.

**More info:** http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Good luck.